# What is the best way to filter this object using lodash or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I am having an object like this

```
 var result = {
    case1: {
        documents: [{
            versionSeriesId: 'BkO9EXxL',
            documentTypeId: '80',
            isDeleted: false
        }],
        answer: true
    },
    case2: {
        documents: [{
            versionSeriesId: 'BkO9EXxL',
            documentTypeId: '80',
            isDeleted: false
        }],
        answer: true
    },
    case3: {
        documents: []
    },
    case4: {
        documents: [{
            versionSeriesId: 'BkO9EXxL',
            documentTypeId: '80',
            isDeleted: false
        }],
        answer: false
    }
}
```

I want to filter the object which is having the **answer:true** only. The result should be like this:

```
{
    case1: {
        documents: [{
            versionSeriesId: 'BkO9EXxL',
            documentTypeId: '80',
            isDeleted: false
        }],
        answer: true
    },
    case2: {
        documents: [{
            versionSeriesId: 'BkO9EXxL',
            documentTypeId: '80',
            isDeleted: false
        }],
        answer: true
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `Object.keys(result).filter(key => result[key].answer === true)` will get you a list of keys, but not an object.

Comment: @Jeevan, do you want to modify the initial object `result` or create a new one?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this quickly and without the need for an external library just by using `Object.keys` and then use the `Array.forEach` method to compile a new object.

```
var filtered = {};
Object.keys(result).forEach(function(item) {
  if (result[item].answer === true) {
    filtered[item] = result[item];
  }
});
```

Test with the snippet below:

```js
var result = {
  case1: {
    documents: [{
      versionSeriesId: 'BkO9EXxL',
      documentTypeId: '80',
      isDeleted: false
    }],
    answer: true
  },
  case2: {
    documents: [{
      versionSeriesId: 'BkO9EXxL',
      documentTypeId: '80',
      isDeleted: false
    }],
    answer: true
  },
  case3: {
    documents: []
  },
  case4: {
    documents: [{
      versionSeriesId: 'BkO9EXxL',
      documentTypeId: '80',
      isDeleted: false
    }],
    answer: false
  }
}

var filtered = {};
Object.keys(result).forEach(function(item) {
  if (result[item].answer === true) {
    filtered[item] = result[item];
  }
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Lodash `pickBy` function like this:

```
_.pickBy(result, function(c){return c.answer});
```

`pickBy` "creates an object composed of the object properties *predicate* returns truthy for" ([docs](https://lodash.com/docs#pickBy)). In your example, you want an object with the cases for which `answer` is truthy, so the predicate just returns that value.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys()` gives you the keys of your array and allows you to iterate through the properties. Then you can filter them based on your criterion and add the correct properties to a new object.

```
var out = {};

Object.keys(result).filter(function(item) {
    return result[item].answer === true;
}).map(function(item) {
    out[item] = result[item];
});
```

**Docs**

- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)